# Wrong SQL Result Condition

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having a bit of a problem with some code where a have a query which should come back false and it's returning true.

First I have an sql query to an id that does not exist:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id='1' "); //There no id with value of 1
```

Then I've added a var_dump to see what's on:

```
var_dump($result);
```

and after a condition:

```
if ($result==0) {
  echo 'No results where found';
} else {
  echo 'Some results where found';
}
```

Here's the result of the var_dump

```
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(12) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

Some results where found

The result should be: No results where found and as you can see above, it's return: Some results where found

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: your result and table doesnt make sense. if you are doing SELECT * you should have all fields, however ID is not even part of your result set.

Comment: Where are you seeing table info @azngunit81?

Comment: result set is just a resource object , to get rows from result set you use mysqli_fetch_array/assoc .. And i think you are getting empty resultset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `mysqli_num_rows()` to see if the query has some rows something as

```
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count == 0){
 // no result
}else{
 // there is data and do whatever you want
}
```

Check the documentation of `mysqli_query()` and the return part
https://www.php.net/mysqli_query

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
> EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
> other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your `id` field is an `integer`, so:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id=1
```

should work